# How Can I get by simple code the Checked RadioButton From Group of RadioButtons Located in same panel in C#?

Tags: c#

I've a C# Windows Form Application that contains multiple Panels , each panel contains group of Radio Buttons.Is There a simple way to get just the checked RadioButton by code instead of checking every Radio Button in each group whether it is checked or not ? please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(Control control in panel.Controls)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = control as RadioButton;
    if (radioButton != null && radioButton.Checked)
        return radioButton;
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need but you could of course have a loop for every panel as well and put all the items in a List<RadioButton>

Comment: Thanks openshac but how could i make a List<RadioButton> ?